# Prisma GraphQL nested document

Tags: mongodb, nested, graphql, prisma

How can I query (an undefined) number of nested elements from my document?
I would like to get the list of items without having to go

```
  menus {
    id
    items {
        id
        name
        items {
            id
            name
            ............
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I have a prisma schema (MongoDB) that looks like this

```
enum MenuType {
  MAIN
  HYPERLINK
}

type Menu {
  id: ID! @id
  type: MenuType!
  name: String!
  title: String
  href: String
  t_blank: Boolean
  items: [Items] 
}

type Items @embedded{
  id: ID! @id
  type: MenuType!
  name: String!
  title: String
  href: String
  t_blank: Boolean
  items: [Items]
}
```

I would like to get all my items with something like this

```
{
  menus {
    id
    items
  }
}
```

Is it possible? Does my consumer need to keep looping through the reponse body?

Comment: What you need is a recursive function on the consumer side to retrieve additional items if items.length > 0.

Comment: not querying a few (max expected) levels deep you can read not enough data/items